# How Can I Add Custom Values(Like Tax) to my All Respective Products Cost at checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, custom, products, taxes

All my products have unique value **"custom value"**, at checkout page, checkout price calculated by original price and customs value as my final price.

- My Need:

**1) sku: 1001, price: 100, custom price: 10, at checkout products value : 110;

2) sku: 1002, price: 200, custom price: 20, at checkout products value : 220;

3) sku: 1003, price: 300, custom price: 30, at checkout products value : 330;

4) sku: 1004, price: 400, custom price: 40, at checkout products value : 440;

5) sku: 1005, price: 500, custom price: 50, at checkout products value : 550;**

My site consists 20k products.

**`Note: Tax not Possible Possible, because tax prepared only based on state and city, but mine every product has unique tax value. So Tax completely not possible`**

> How can I apply Individual products tax for my products?

Comment: you need to create different Tax rules and Tax class and assign it to product. For example create Tax rules for 10 %  Tax and assign that rule to Tax class and assign that Tax class to products  it this way you can manage Tax on product.

Comment: OR you can create your own quote total field "GST" and apply your product "custom value" logic in That total. in that case you can manage it using dynamic values

Comment: Second solution would be good i guess

Comment: could you pls explain in detail of your second solution.

Comment: check [this example](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/01/27/magento-add-fee-discount-order-total/)

Comment: above example is based on magento version 1.6. there are some changes in new version

Comment: GST is based on product group i guess.so you can create Tax class and rules based on product group and assign that Tax class to product that will also work for you

Comment: @MineshPatel : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61342/how-can-i-add-custom-valueslike-tax-to-my-all-respective-products-cost-at-check

Comment: @MineshPatel : It's working good, thank You.

Comment: Post as answer may be useful to others

Comment: sure let me do that

Comment: i have added comment as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GST is based on product group i guess.so you can create Tax class and rules based on each product group and assign that Tax class to that product group.

**For example :**

for example electronic products , GST will be same for all electronic products and for clothing products , GST will be same for all clothing products

For more details read this [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61342/how-can-i-add-custom-valueslike-tax-to-my-all-respective-products-cost-at-check)

Answer (score 3):

Its just a fix but you can try to add custom option " Tax Price " with only one **value** and assign the **price** to it. And Make it required. So when a customer add the product to cart he/she has to select the custom options and the tax will be levied on the product.

[image]

Comment: :: add custom option " Tax Price " with only one value and assign the price to it  ":: how can i do it,, did you mean attribute?

Comment: Actually, this is for GST,  as you know every product has unique tax value.

Comment: please see the picture edit. For attribute you need to do coding but this can inculpated in the default magneto work flow.

Comment: Did this solve what you looking for @Rathinam

Comment: @RiddhishBhayani why customer select GST ?. GST is TAX can not be set as product option